# Concurrency issue with Entity Framework 4.1 Mysql Code First

Tags: mysql, concurrency, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

I am using Entity FrameWork 4.1 With the MySQL database and the MySQL connector 6.4.3 with a code first approach.

Currently, I am attempting to configure concurrency with a timestamp field.  The following is the code within my model object:

```
[Timestamp]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
[Column(TypeName = "timestamp")]
public DateTime RowVersion { get; set; }
```

When I generate the database the RowVersion field is created with the proper trigger to update itself when the row is modified.

Whenever I attempt to update this row I get the following exception:

```
{"Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries."}
```

Here is the sql being generated:

```
BEGIN
UPDATE `mytable` SET `StartDt`='2011-07-27 11:37:01' WHERE `ID` = 1;
SELECT `RowVersion` FROM `mytable` WHERE  row_count() > 0 AND `ID`=last_insert_id()
ROLLBACK
```

I think the problem is with the "last_insert_id()" call.  This call will not return any results which causes the exception.  Why would the entity framework be making that call on an update and what do I need to do to fix this?

Thanks!
AFrieze

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem? Someone submitted a problem on the MySQL site, but it was closed without a fix. Bug #57629. The MySQL Connector is adding the last_insert_id() incorrectly instead of using rows primary key.

Comment: Not directly.  I worked around it by using this Attribute: 
        [ConcurrencyCheck]